# No errors, label seems like it should change to the indicated text but its not

Tags: c#

Can anybody tell me why this is doing nothing? `pcNameLabel.Text` is supposed to be changing to bob when `StatTransfer()` is called by `FighterButtonClick`. According to the debugger everything is working right.

I've taken out some extra variables and stuff unrelated to the problem at hand.

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        public static string VariableLabel1;
        public static string Variable2;

        Random _r = new Random();

        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();          
        }

        void CLoop()
        {
            while(true)
            {
                SetInfo();
            }
        }

        public void SetInfo()
        {
            this.pcNameLabel.Text = VariableLabel1;
        }

        void ChClassButtClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CharStats form = new CharStats();
            form.Show();
        }
    }
```

This is a seperate windows form window.

```
public partial class CharStats : Form
    {
        public CharStats()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        void StatTransfer()
        {
            MainForm Mform = new MainForm();
            MainForm.VariableLabel1 = "Bob";
            Mform.SetInfo();
        }

        void FighterButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Fighter();
            StatTransfer();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In these lines

```
void StatTransfer()
{
   // This is a new instance of MainForm, not the original one
   MainForm Mform = new MainForm();
   MainForm.VariableLabel1 = "Bob";
   Mform.SetInfo();
}
```

you create a new instance of MainForm and this instance is never displayed. This hidden instance contains the label that you are trying to change, but you cant't see it.

The simplest workaround to the problem is to pass the calling instance of `MainForm` to `CharStats` form when you initialize it

```
void ChClassButtClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     CharStats form = new CharStats(this);
     form.Show();
}
```

Now you should change the constructor of `CharStats` to receive the passed instance and save it in a global variable inside the CharStats class

```
public partial class CharStats : Form
{
    private MainForm _callingForm;
    public CharStats(MainForm callingForm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _callingForm = callingForm;
    }
    .....
```

And use this saved instance where you need it

```
    void StatTransfer()
    {
        _callingForm.VariableLabel1 = "Bob";
        callingForm.SetInfo();
    }
}
```

**EDIT** By the way, you dnn't need to use static variable for this to work. Simply change the method MainForm.SetInfo to receive a string and pass Bob when you call it

```
 public void SetInfo(string newText)
 {
        this.pcNameLabel.Text = newText;
 }
```

From CharStats

```
void StatTransfer()
{
    callingForm.SetInfo("Bob");
}
```

Comment: Oh I understand. I thought that was a way to solve my previous issue where I couldn't call use a static method to change the non static `this.pcNameLabel.Text`. I guess in a fashion I did solve it, except now I've created a second instance that is never shown which is holding the data. While what I want to be doing is modifying the data in the first instance. I think I'm going to have to find a new way of doing this. Thanks :) I'm new to instances

Comment: If you follow my answer, you don't have two instances of MainForm, but Always the original one. The one that calls the CharStats form in its button click event. You pass the instance reference (this) to the CharStats form and inside that you use the passed in reference

Comment: Hey thanks a lot. I actually understand what your explaining there. I've integrated that code but now my debugger is telling me `'charactertest.CharStats.CharStats(charactertest.MainForm)' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial` and I have no idea what that means

Comment: Sorry but can't follow you on this. Not enough context to understand. It is probably better to write a new question referencing this and explaining the failing code. You could get more attention from other people

Answer (score 0):

`MainForm` is not set to display anywhere. I believe you want to add it to your `CharStats` form like so:

```
void StatTransfer()
{
    MainForm Mform = new MainForm();
    MainForm.VariableLabel1 = "Bob";
    Mform.SetInfo();
    this.Controls.Add(Mform);
}
```

Comment: Oh `MainForm` is the primary one that starts up first. I call the`CharStats` form with a button in `MainForm` I can get both to shew up fine the text on `MainForm` just doesnt update with the info from `CharStats`